# POSH: New-Event on Variable changed or filled

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

i like to trigger a event when a variable is filled / changed or when it has a defined value.
Is one of these possible ?

i have a barcode scanner connected to Serial running in a different runspace.
and created a synchronised hashtable to share the barcode.

i want to trigger a event when the hashtable.Value contains a barcode
so i can add it to the GUI without blocking the current thread.

(i know i could make a System.Timers.Timer object en poll every 100ms) but i rather use a event.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing how your UI is made up, this example is rather basic but shows how you can use an observablecollection to bind with a listbox to auto-update the listbox whenever something is added to the collection (even from another runspace).

```
$uiHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$uiHash.ObservableCollection = $Script:observableCollection = New-Object System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection[string]
$runspaceHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$newRunspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$newRunspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$newRunspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"          
$newRunspace.Open()
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("uiHash",$uiHash)          
$newRunspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("runspaceHash",$runspaceHash) 
$psCmd = [PowerShell]::Create().AddScript({   
#Build the GUI
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Initial Window" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen" 
    Width = "313" Height = "800" ShowInTaskbar = "True" Background = "lightgray"> 
    <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <StackPanel >
            <TextBox  IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap">
                Type something and click Add
            </TextBox>
            <TextBox x:Name = "inputbox"/>
            <Button x:Name="button1" Content="Add"/>
            <Button x:Name="button2" Content="Remove"/>
            <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                <ListBox x:Name="listbox" SelectionMode="Extended" />
            </Expander >
        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer >
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$uiHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
 
#Connect to Controls
$uiHash.inputbox = $uiHash.Window.FindName('inputbox')
$uiHash.button1 = $uiHash.Window.FindName('button1')
$uiHash.button2 = $uiHash.Window.FindName('button2')
$uiHash.listbox = $uiHash.Window.FindName('listbox')

$uiHash.Window.Add_SourceInitialized({
    #Have to have something initially in the collection
    $uiHash.listbox.ItemsSource = $UIhash.observableCollection
    $uiHash.inputbox.Focus()
})
 
#Events
$uiHash.button1.Add_Click({
     $UIhash.observableCollection.Add($uiHash.inputbox.text)
     $uiHash.inputbox.Clear()
})
$uiHash.button2.Add_Click({
    ForEach ($item in @($uiHash.listbox.SelectedItems)) {
        $UIhash.observableCollection.Remove($item)
    }
}) 
$uiHash.Window.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
})
$psCmd.Runspace = $newRunspace
$Handle = $psCmd.BeginInvoke()
```

With the window open, you can now send data to the observablecollecton by way of the Dispatcher on the Window. Each time the collection is updated, the listbox will be updated in the same way (add, remove or clear).

```
# While form is open, you can send data to the form by updating the observablecollection
# This has to be done on the UI thread though!
$uiHash.Window.Dispatcher.Invoke('Normal',[Action]{
    $UIhash.observableCollection.Add(1)
})
```

Code below added just to ensure that everything gets disposed after the form has been closed in this example.

```
# Once form has closed, make sure to dispose of everything
$psCmd.EndInvoke($Handle)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea but you can try adding  a scriptmethod to your hastable that check if value is barcode and that do something before call the add() method:

```
$instance = @{}

add-member -Force -in $instance scriptmethod MyAdd {
    param( [string]$bar = "bar", [string]$foo = "foo"  )

    #pseudo code
    if  ($foo is barcode) { do this stuff in the gui }
    #end of pseudo code

    $this.add($bar,$foo) # call the native hastable add method
}
```